# Firebase Realtime Database login with specific user

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to log in from my android apps to my firebase realtime database. after login, i must get some info about the logged-in user. But it always shows the last(last record from JSON tree) user info from the JSON tree.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
users = mDatabase.getReference("tbl_client");
userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
passWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passWord);
login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {      signIn(userName.getText().toString(),passWord.getText().toString());
            }
        });
```

```
private void signIn(final String username,final String password){
       users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User usersBean = user.getValue(User.class);
                    if (usersBean.password.equals(passWord.getText().toString().trim())) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginCardOverlap.this,userBean.getCustomerID(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginCardOverlap.this, "Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginCardOverlap.this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

the userBean.getCustomerID() always shows the record of the last item from the realtime database JSON tree. the image depicts the database structure:
https://gomaxtracker.com/gmx_realtime_database_structure.png

Comment: There's a chance it's remembering an older version of your database. Try deleting all application data (NOT just reinstalling, delete the data from your phone's 'Apps' menu) and try again.

Comment: thanks for your comments... i tried to delete all cache from emulator and re-run the app in emulator and having the same result.... it always shows the last records' customer_Id

Comment: Uh huh. In your screenshot, both users have 111222 for password. Are you sure other users have different ones? Also add some "Log.d" calls, to see if your "usersBean" objects have the expected passwords and if your "passWord.getText().toString().trim()" is what you expect it to be.

Comment: actually i set same password for all of my users... but if i just compare the username it does not work... even the Log.d() shows the perfect username vs the stored username. if (usersBean.username == userName.getText().toString().trim()) {}

Comment: hello.. do i have to change anything in my User Class?

Comment: You haven't posted your User class. Are the passwords actual passwords that will be picked by your users? Because in that case, what you should really do is use Firebase Authentication for logging in. You shouldn't have direct access to the passwords of your users, that would be so wrong.

Comment: You should also change your database scheme. Now you're making the app download the data of every user, just to use the data of the current user. Instead of using an array for tbl_client, you should use a map. Then it will be super easy to get only the data of your current user.

Comment: Hello Stratubas, thank you very much for your suggestion... can u pls give me an example of map function instead of using an array? by the way.. my user class is as follows:

Comment: package com.material.components.activity; public class User {
  public String username;
  public String password;
  public String customer_id;
  public String name;
  public User() {
  } public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public String getName() { return name; }

  public String getCustomerID() {
    return customer_id;
  }public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Make your users authenticate using Firebase Authentication (using their emails). Then you can use their UIDs to identify them in your database.

[image: Authentication]

[image: RTDB]

Note that there are no usernames and passwords in the database anymore.

The `email` is not required to be in the database, but putting in there makes it easier for you / the administrator to get the emails.

The extra `row_in_table` field is to make it possible to sort the clients in a "all clients" view.

Then in your app, to show the information of a single client, you only have to read at `tbl_client/{UID}`, not the entire `tbl_client`.